# C# Chart Line Annotation disappears when anchor point is off Axis View

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, charts, data-visualization

I'm sure this problem has a simple solution that I'm not aware of but I'm going to ask anyway. I have this code:

```
HorizontalLineAnnotation h = new HorizontalLineAnnotation();
h.AnchorX = startOfNewGraph;
h.Width = newGraphWidth;
h.AxisX = resultGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
h.AxisY = resultGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;
h.IsSizeAlwaysRelative = false;
h.ClipToChartArea = resultGraph.ChartAreas[0].Name;
originalHLAAnchors.Add(h.AnchorX);
originalHLAWidths.Add(h.Width);
resultGraph.Annotations.Add(h);
```

My problem is that the annotation disappears when my graph view is scaled to where its AnchorX is outside of the view. I would like to keep it on so that even if neither end of the annotation is in the view, I can still see the line between them. Here's what I tried to do to remedy it:

```
private void resultGraph_AxisViewChanged(object sender, ViewEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Axis == resultGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX)
        {
            ResizeHorizontalAnnotations();
        }
    }

private void ResizeHorizontalAnnotations()
    {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < resultGraph.Annotations.Count; i++)
        {
            if (resultGraph.Annotations[i] is HorizontalLineAnnotation)
            {
                if (originalHLAAnchors[count] < resultGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum)
                {
                    resultGraph.Annotations[i].AnchorX = resultGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum + 0.0005;
                    if ((originalHLAAnchors[count] + originalHLAWidths[count]) >= resultGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum)
                    {
                        resultGraph.Annotations[i].Width = resultGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum - resultGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        resultGraph.Annotations[i].Width -= resultGraph.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum - originalHLAAnchors[count];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    resultGraph.Annotations[i].AnchorX = originalHLAAnchors[count];
                    resultGraph.Annotations[i].Width = originalHLAWidths[count];
                }
                resultGraph.Annotations[i].Visible = true;
               count++;
            }
        }
        resultGraph.UpdateAnnotations();
    }
```

However, this code didn't seem to work either. The annotations didn't show when I tried it first, so I added 0.005 to the AnchorX to see if it had to be a little over the view minimum. This didn't work either. When I check the local values of the annotations, the numbers are correct. The annotations just either don't show up correctly or at all. UpdateAnnotations() zooms out the view and disables my annotations, too.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `Annotations` which are anchored to a position either directly with the `AnchorX` property or by using an `AnchorDataPoint` disappear once that anchor is no longer in the viewscale.

Not sure if that is a bug or a feature, but you can work around by setting the position directly.

So you should use the `h.Width` along with the `h.X` properties to size and position the `Annotation`:

```
    h.X = startOfNewGraph;
    h.Width = newGraphWidth;
```

You didn't show us how you positioned the `Annoation` vertically; maybe anchored to a `DataPoint`? Or by setting the `Y` property? Both should work now for zooming into the x-axis.

Note that both `Annotation.X` and `Annotation.AnchorX` have a default value of `double.NaN`, which in chart-lingo usually means 'automatic'; in this case I guess it means 'doesn't apply'.

If you set both properties, I find that `Annotation.X` wins. So setting it back to `double.NaN` will make `Annotation.AnchorX` active again.

Comment: I finally got back to it now and your first sentence is the answer. All I needed to to was to set the value to X instead of AnchorX and it worked fine even when X was out of view. Knew it was something simple!

Answer (score 0):

Use a series instead and you don´t need to bother about the anchor and resizing issues with the .net chart annotations:

```
private void Line(Point start, Point end)
{
    chart1.Series.Add("line");
    chart1.Series["line"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
    chart1.Series["line"].Color = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    chart1.Series["line"].Points.AddXY(start.X, start.Y);
    chart1.Series["line"].Points.AddXY(end.X, end.Y);
}
```